# Parsing Xml is throwing a weird invalid charecter exception

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

My application is trying to parse an XML and it is throwing the following exception,

> An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x52) was found in the element content of the document.

I'm 100% sure the XML is valid. but still I don't know why I'm getting this exception.

Any Ideas on what could be the cause for this exception?

code I'm using to read the xml files is:

```
String policyFile = filename;
    try {
        String overRide = System.getProperty("TEST_POLICY_FILE");
        if (overRide != null) {
            policyFile = overRide;
        }

        //          URL urlToPolicyFile = new URL(policyFile);
        //          InputStream is = urlToPolicyFile.openStream();
        //InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(policyFile);
        // get XML Parser instance
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setIgnoringComments(true);
        factory.setValidating(false);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        builder.setEntityResolver(VacEntityResolver.getInstance());
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(policyFile);
        // parse input file
        Document policyDocument = builder.parse(inputSource);
        Builder policyBuilder = new Builder();

        // load decl-policies file into cache
        visitDeclarativePolicies(policyDocument, policyBuilder);
        m_myPolicyCache = policyBuilder.getPolicyCache();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new InvalidPolicyFileException(policyFile);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new InvalidPolicyFileException(policyFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new InvalidPolicyFileException(policyFile);
    }
```

The line,

`Document policyDocument = builder.parse(inputSource);`

is the one which is throwing the error

One interesting fact about this issue is, it is happening only in production environment. The same Xml file is not producing any issues neither in my dev environment, nor in testing environment. Sorry for not sharing the file. It is a file, I should not share. But the same input file is not producing any issues in my Dev environment.

The issue seems to be weird to me because, it is throwing exception for the character 0x52 which is 'R'.

Answer (score 0):

usually it's better to give more input (for example post a minimized version of the input which still shows that behavior), but going from what you've given it's possible that a lower case r is expected vs an upper case R (that would make you think this is valid but a tight syntax checker would mark it as invalid)

[Edited following question info addition]

A suspect for dev/production difference is OS difference.  Is your machine Unix and Production Windows or the other way around?  In those cases the way the OS creates and reads files may influence the content you get, and parsing may differ.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my post with few more info. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode: 0x52 is a capital R. I am unsure why you would be getting this error. Could you please post the code you are trying to execute or a sample of the data where this error is being thrown?

http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?names=-&utf8=0x

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my post with few more info. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The only situation I can think of where "R" would be an invalid character is immediately following a "high surrogate". But rather than letting us guess, you need to give us more information.

I would say from my experience that being "100% sure" your XML is valid, when your parser tells you it isn't, is not a good starting point for getting to the bottom of the problem.

Comment: hi Kay, The reason why I'm saying XML is valid, the same XML is used in Dev environment and not producing any issues. It is happening in production machine alone. Also I dont see any "high surrogate" in the input file.

Comment: Well, since you're not prepared to share your XML, I really can't comment on what's wrong with it. In fact, either the XML is wrong or the parser is wrong, and you haven't told us what the XML is or what parser you are using, so you're asking us to make wild guesses.